# How to copy price + quantity data from one Excel sheet to another if the SKUs in the rows match

Tags: vba, excel

I have two separate excel files (File1 and File2). Both are sheets containing data for the same products in a store, with price, quantity, and item SKU/ID data, but each file is formatted and arranged differently.

I want Excel to look in File2, compare it to File1, find the "price" and "quantity" data for a specific SKU that is in both sheets, and copy the "price" and "quantity" data from File2 to File1.

For example, say I've got a product with the SKU of "A3210". This product is listed in both Excel files with the SKU listed in each as well, each in it's own row with the "price" and "quantity" data. File2 has more accurate price and quantity data, so I want to copy the correct data over to File1, and replace the "price" and "quantity" data in that row for that specific product/SKU number. But I don't want to overwrite the entire row, just the data from those specific price + quantity cells, because the row has other data that I need.

- Screencap of File1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iSxD.jpg
- Screencap of File2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fUav.jpg

Like I said, I want an Excel macro that tells Excel to compare File1 and File2, and replace the Price and Quantity data in File1 with the Price and Quantity data from File 2. The data has to match up properly in accordance with the SKU; the SKU has to be the same from each row.

Any help? VERY limited knowledge in VBA and all that; not sure how to logically do this or program it so I'm coming here. Thanks in advance everyone...

EDIT: Recorded macro of me adding formula:

```
Sub stackoverflow_reverb_formula_input()
'
' stackoverflow_reverb_formula_input Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],[invexpa.xlsx]Sheet1!R2433C5:R2433C20,8,FALSE)"
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],[invexpa.xlsx]Sheet1!R2433C5:R2433C20,16,FALSE)"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E547"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("E2:E547").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L547"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("L2:L547").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I know you state you want a macro to perform this, but would instead be open to using an Excel formula?  It sounds like a VLOOKUP would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to change data in a file so I can upload that file to an online store, which will update my price and quantity on there. If I use a formula, would I still be able to save the file properly and upload it to the web?

If so, then I'm all ears... willing to do whatever works.

Comment: To return values to the right of the SKU you can use the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). For values to the left of the SKU you will need an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) pair. The formula results can be resolved to their values with Copy, Paste Special, Values.

Answer (score 0):

In your File 1, for Inventory, use the formula:
`=VLOOKUP(F2,'[File2Name.xlsx]SheetName'!$E$2:$T$1000,8,FALSE)`
And in the Price use:
`=VLOOKUP(F2,'[File2Name.xlsx]SheetName'!$E$2:$T$1000,16,FALSE)`

For these formulas, replace:

- "File2Name" with File 2's name
- "SheetName" with the name of the sheet File 2's data is on
- The "1000" in $T$1000 with the last row number of your data.

Then just copy this formula all the way down in both columns.

Try this macro to automatically fill in the formula (you must have the sheet that you're copying TO open):

```
Sub stackoverflow_reverb_formula_input()

Dim intDataRow As Integer, intCurrentRow As Integer
intDataRow = Workbooks("invexpa.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=[A1]).Row
intCurrentRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=[A1]).Row
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],[invexpa.xlsx]Sheet1!R1C5:R" + CStr(intDataRow) + "C20,8,FALSE)"
Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],[invexpa.xlsx]Sheet1!R1C5:R" + CStr(intDataRow) + "C20,16,FALSE)"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" + CStr(intCurrentRow)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" + CStr(intCurrentRow)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Alright, I remembered the reason why I want a macro and not a formula: I'm going to be re-downloading updated versions of my product sheet frequently.

I'd be going to my online store, downloading an excel sheet with my product quantity and price data, and then I want to run a macro to compare it to a different excel sheet that has more accurate/updated price and quantity data. I want it to grab the more accurate data and replace the old data in the first sheet I downloaded from my online store, then reupload.

If I put in a formula, I'm going to have to enter in the formula every time (cont)

Comment: I re-download my product sheet. Unless there is a VBA macro that will do this for me?

Comment: If you'd like to record a macro of yourself entering this formula then posting it here, I can modify it so that it will adjust to any number of rows.  That way it will be a macro as you desire.

Comment: That would be fantastic, thank you. Do I enter in the formula in the specific column once, or do I enter in the formula once for each cell? I have hundreds of cells... if I have to enter it in each cell, is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: Also, I can't manually enter in the "last row number" of my data, because for each file, I would be adding new products in frequently, so the "last row number" would be constantly changing. Is there something I can enter to always get the "last row number" no matter how many rows I have? Like a "get last row with data's number" thing?

Comment: Yes, I can add that in once I get the macro that you've recorded.  That's what I meant by "adjust to any number of rows."  And you can simply copy the formula and paste it down to the bottom of your data.

Comment: Right, sorry, wasn't reading your comment clearly :P.

I've recorded the macro and added it to an edit on my original question post. Didn't have enough room here.

Also, when I entered in the formulas you gave me, they didn't work. I just get an #N/A in each cell. Tried to edit the numbers and column letters in the formulas, and it still didn't work.



Thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Getting an error that says "Can't execute code in break mode".

Comment: That means that you were currently running a macro.  You need to stop that macro (whatever it was) before you can run this one.  If you open the visual basic page, there's a STOP button (near the top, play, pause, stop) that you will have to click before you can run the new macro.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error: "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined".

Thanks for all your help so far...

Comment: My mistake, I missed an "s" on Workbook, line 4 (the "intDataRow =" line).  Edited to accommodate.

Comment: Getting an RTE now:

Run-time error: '-2147352565 (8002000b)': The item with the specified name wasn't found.

Comment: It doesn't tell me a row; it gives me that RTE and gives me an option to debug. When I click debug, it points to this line of code and highlights it yellow:

intDataRow = Workbooks("invexpa.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=[A1]).Row

Comment: Do you currently have the invexpa.xlsx workbook open?  And the sheet name is "Sheet1"?  Both of those must be true for the macro to work.

Comment: Yeah, both the sheet I want to update, and invexpa.xlsx are open. The sheet name is Sheet1.

.xlsx is a Excel 97-2003 workbook file, right?

Comment: The file extension for an Excel 97-2003 workbook is .xls (no ending x).

Comment: OK, I changed the file extension to .xls in the code. Now, no RTE, but it opens up a prompt for me to open a file when I run the macro. I tried to open the invexpa.xls file, then another Open File prompt came up again... tried to open invexpa.xls again. Came up four times I believe. I hit cancel the last two times, and it left the columns I want edited with a bunch of #N/A left in place.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, you should already have the invexpa.xls file open when you run the code, but you're have active that page that you're inputting the formulas to?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the vlookup function to do this.

A vlookup is a spreadsheet function which looks for a specified value down the leftmost column of a table and when it finds that value, it returns a value from the same row.

We need to tell it what to search for, where to search for it and which column number to return the value from.

A vlookup looks for a value in the leftmost column of a table and then returns a value from the row that the searched for value is found (how far along that row is determined by you).

The vlookup formula consists of 4 parts:

1.SearchFor this is the value that is being searched for. In our dictionary example it would be the word “elucidate”.

2.WhereToSearch this is the range in which to search and in which the answer lives. In our example, it would be columns A to C.

3.WhichColumn this is the column in the WhereToSearch range which has the answer in it. In our dictionary example, it would be the third column.

4.NearOrExact you decide whether the vlookup should search for a close value or an exact value (in our dictionary example we would set this to false as we do want it to search for the exact word “elucidate”).

Structure of the vlookup formula:

=vlookup ( SearchFor , WhereToSearch , WhichColumn , NearOrExact )

[Source: www.excelvlookuphelp.com](http://www.excelvlookuphelp.com)